# 'NoneType' object is not iterable in scrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write scrapper for "free-proxy.cz" website, however, I am facing a problem

I know my "port" section is wrong, but I don't know the problem and how to fix it.

here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import base64


urls = ['http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/all/socks5/date/all',
       'http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/all/socks5/date/all/2',
       'http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/all/socks5/date/all/3',
       'http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/all/socks5/date/all/4',
       'http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/all/socks5/date/all/5',
]

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'proxy_list'})
    for row in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
        for ip in row.find('script'):
            text=base64.b64decode(ip[29:-2:])
        for port in row.find('span', attrs='fport'):
            print(port.get_text())
    #ipadd=print(prt.decode('utf-8')+':'+ports)
```

** I commented the last line because the port grabber is not working correct.

the result of running the above code is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LOCATION\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    for port in row.find('span', attrs='fport'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
80
45554
1080
1080
```

what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `row in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr')` sometimes returns `NoneType`, hence throwing an error. You should be able to overcome it by encapsulating everything in a `try` - `except` block. Like this:

```py
import requests
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = 'http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/all/socks5/date/all'

i = 1

while i < 5:
    if i == 1:
        r = requests.get(BASE_URL)
    else:
        r = requests.get(BASE_URL + f'/{i}')
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'proxy_list'})

    for row in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
        try:
            ip =  base64.b64decode(row.select_one('script').get_text()[29:-2:])
            port = row.select_one('span').get_text()
            print(f'IP:     { ip }')
            print(f'Port:   { port } \n')
        except:
            pass

    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    span_rows = row.find('span', attrs='fport')
    if span_rows is not None:
        for port in span_rows:
            print(port.get_text())
```

Comment: The problem of "NoneType' is solved, however, the port grabber is still incorrect. did I select "span" and "fport" wrong ? the final results are incorrect